# Building an app for two customers on Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-build

We have an app we want to build for two customers. We use grunt to inject different CSS before doing Cordova build. We are able to build two apps with different icons and display names. However we are unable to install both apps on the same phone at the same time. If we change the widget ID in config.xml we do get two apps that will not overwrite each other but one will not run because the widget ID causes a new package structure to be created for our app.

How can I create two apps from a single code base that can be installed side by side?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to install an app twice, they have to have different package names.

But only changeing the package name is not enough. The folders in the src folder are created like the package name (f.e. 'com.stackoverflow.app' results in folder 'com' with subfolder 'stackoverflow' and in it subfolder 'app'.

I think it would be easier to create an app for each customer and copy the files with grunt from one to another.